# How do I replace only a portion of the following regex (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning regexs and file saving. As exercise, I wanted to turn every `func` in a file into `function`:

```
data.replace(/func\((.*)\)/g, 'function')
```

The problem is that the `func`s in the file now end up like this:

```
var thisfunc = function {

}
```

Instead of this:

```
var thisfunc = function() {

}
```

How should I do it so that the regex only replaces the `func` keyword?

**EDIT:**

input:

```
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', func(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('OK: ' + filename)
  var newData = data.replace(/func\((.*)\)/g, 'function')
  console.log(newData)
})

var thisfunc = func() {

}
```

Comment: what's the input? and btw, did you really learn about file saving in javascript?

Comment: @Amit Joki updated. See my **EDIT**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

match and replace only the opening parenthesis, 
especially if those can be nested like in `func(a, func(b))`:

```
data.replace(/func\(/g, 'function(')
```

Note: in environments where replacement string needs escape sequence for `(`, use `function\(`, this is not necessary in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is also matching the arguments (in the parenthesis), and the whole match will be replaced by only `function`. You can either:

- exclude the arguments from the matching, e.g. with [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

  ```
  data.replace(/func(?=\((.*)\))/g, 'function')
  ```
- or "re"insert them in the [replacement string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter):

  ```
  data.replace(/func\((.*)\)/g, 'function($1)')
  ```

Comment: greedy operator is no good here e.g. `func() {a} + func() {...` and lazy won't help either if parentheses can be nested

Comment: @Aprillion: You're right, I've only tackled the concrete problem that the OP had. Of course, regex is in general not the right tool to process non-regular languages.

Comment: @Bergi Hey thanks a lot. Could you explain the replacement string one? I can't figure out why the replacement works when put inside the parentheses.

Comment: @alexchenco it would replace all the matched characters . In your case the following `()` is matced.

Comment: @alexchenco sorry for previous confusion, it works fine in your case, but it would not work if you had `func() ... func()` on the same line or if you had the parameters spread on multiple lines like `func(a,\n  b)`

Answer (score 1):

Here you actually need a positive lookahead assertion. And you don't need to use capturing group.

```
data.replace(/func(?=\(.*\))/g, 'function')
```

OR

`.*?` here will do a non-greedy match of any character zero or more times.

```
data.replace(/func(?=\(.*?\))/g, 'function')
```

`(?=\(.*?\))` Asserts that the keyword `func` must be followed by pair of parenthesis which may or may-not contain arguments.

Comment: or `data.replace(/func(?=\([^()]*\))/g, 'function')`

Comment: assuming arguments themselves do not contain parentheses

Comment: that's why i added both. but yours will replace all `func(` to `function(` even it won't have any closing bracket.

Comment: it will replace `func(` without closing parenthesis, so what? yours will do the same for `func(\n{blah()}`, just a little bit more slowly

Comment: there are many cases where yours and mine would fail. I don't know whats your actual problem is..

Comment: why do you call it `fail`? it is undefined behaviour at worst, and I think it is a good think that `func(` will be replaced to `function(` regardless of closing paren for any practical purpose

Comment: hm, there is actually a use case where your answer would not work `func(a,\n b)`